# Why solving linear equations is taking a quotient by some subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Linear equation can be represented by a linear form, and its solution space is the same thing as kernel of this form. The same is true for system of linear equations.

But [this lecture notes](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/qg-spring2007/s07week01b.pdf) suggest that solution space also can be set in contra-variant way. Represented in exact sequence (in 3-dismensions) it looks like:

```
Equations -> <x,y,z> -> Solutions -> 0
```

there each element of 'Equations' basis maps to formal representation of some equation in `<x,y,z>`. So solution space will be quotient rather than kernel.

I can not understand why this is true. Why? Is such representation functional?

Comment: I am sorry for my English. If my explanation of the map is not understandable, you can definition on second page of the lecture notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional space and let $W \subseteq V$ be a subspace. Denote by $W^{0}$ the annihilator of $W$. Then we have a natural isomorphism $W^{*} \cong V^{*}/W^{0}$ obtained by mapping $[\varphi] \in V^{*}/W^{0}$ to the linear functional $\varphi|_{W}$.

Suppose we are given $k$ linear functionals $(\varphi)_{i=1}^k$ on $V$. We can define a map $T \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^k$ by $T(v) = (\varphi_1(v), \dots, \varphi_k(v))$ and then $\ker(T)$ describes the solution space of the system of linear equations

$$ \varphi_1(v) = \dots = \varphi_k(v) = 0. $$

Now, we can look at this from the dual point of view. Consider the dual map $T^{*} \colon \left( \mathbb{F}^k \right)^{*} \rightarrow V^{*}$. The natural basis on $\left( \mathbb{F}^k \right)^{*}$ is $e^i$ (the dual to the standard basis on $\mathbb{F}^k$) and we have $T^{*}(e^i) = \varphi_i,$ so the image of $T^{*}$ is precisely the subspace of equations that $\ker(T)$ satisfies. In other words, $\operatorname{Im}(T^{*}) = \ker(T)^0$ and so

$$ \operatorname{coker}(T^{*}) = V^{*}/\operatorname{Im}(T^{*}) = V^{*}/\operatorname{\ker(T)}^{0} \cong \ker(T)^{*}. $$

Thus, the **dual** to the solution set is naturally isomorphic to the cokernel of the dual map. **If** $V = \mathbb{F}^n$ is a free vector space, we can use the natural basis to identify $V$ with $V^{*}$ and also obtain $\ker(T) \approx \operatorname{coker}(T^{*})$ which is what is described in the document.

---

Let me do explicitly his example. We have $V = \mathbb{F}^3$ and $k = 3$ with

$$ \varphi_1(x,y,z) = x + y + z, \,\,\, \varphi_2(x,y,z) = 2x + y, \,\,\, \varphi_3(x,y,z) = 3x + 2y + z. $$

The map $T$ is given by $T(x,y,z) = (x + y + z, 2x + y, 3x + 2y + z)$ and $ \ker(T) = \left< (1,-2,1) \right>$. Here, $x,y,z$ can be thought of as coordinates on $V^{*}$ corresponding to the dual of the standard basis.

Dually, we can consider $V^{*}/ \left< \varphi_1, \varphi_2, \varphi_3 \right>$. If we identify $V$ with $V^{*}$, we see that this space is isomorphic to

$$ \mathbb{F}^3 / \left< (1,1,1), (2,1,0), (3,2,1) \right> = \left< [(1,-2,1) ]\right>. $$

Comment: Thank you, that is awesome!